# Add whatever image name with .jpg extension

Tags: php, string, image, search

I have this simple code:

```
$image = $part["dir"] . "/photo.jpg";

if (false !== (getimagesize($image))) {
    // image resize
}
```

The `$part["dir"]` is the image directory path + the name of the image name. The `getimagesize($image)` will check only for that image string. If I change the name of the image in the folder I get a warring, which I logical because the image string, photo.jpg is not found.
What I would like to do is add whatever image string name is in the folder with the .jpg extension. I know this is simple but I really don't know PHP's built-in functions that well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$images = glob($part["dir"] . "/*.jpg");
$image = $images[0];

if (false !== (getimagesize($image))) {
    // image resize
}
```

or shorter

```
list($image) = glob($part["dir"] . "/*.jpg");

if (false !== (getimagesize($image))) {
    // image resize
}
```

Comment: Uh... missing `glob()`, maybe?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yep :)

Comment: Oh that was so simple :). I did tried the glob() function but didn't knew the list() one. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php
$imagePath = $part["dir"];

foreach(glob($imagePath . '*') as $filename){
    if (false !== (getimagesize($filename))) {
        echo getimagesize($filename) . ' -- ';
    }
}
```

Comment: I *can* try it, but it won't work, so I won't bother.